# pthread_rwlock_rdlock() and pthread_rwlock_wrlock()

Tags: c, multithreading

I can't understand a thing in the specification of the behaviour of these functions.

Imagine this scenario:
T1,T2 and T3 are the names of the threads.
Execute operations in series.

```
    T1 calls pthread_rwlock_rdlock().
    T2 calls pthread_rwlock_wrlock() and wait because 
    rwlock is hold by T1.
    T3 calls pthread_rwlock_rdlock().
    T1 calls pthread_rwlock_unlock().
```

What's up next?

The specification says this:
"The calling thread acquires the read lock if a writer does not hold the lock and there are no writers blocked on the lock"

I can't undestand if T3 will take the rwlock before T2.
I hope yes.
Can you solve my problem?

Comment: T2 requested the lock first and is blocking on it, why would you want T3 to get priority?

Comment: The specification says more than just that.  It also talks about the `Thread Execution Scheduling` which comes into play here.

Comment: @Chris Multiple readers can hold a rw lock concurrently, so one possible scheduling methodology would allow a second reader to come in and acquire the lock while the first reader has the lock even if a writer is waiting to acquire the lock.  It is more efficient overall as you can avoid waiting time in the second reader, but can lead to writer-starvation if there's a continuous stream of readers coming in and acquiring the lock without any breaks.

Comment: T3 calls pthread_rwlock_rdlock() **and waits because T2 is blocked on the lock**. T1 calls pthread_rwlock_unlock() **and T2 acquires the lock**.

Comment: T3 could call `pthread_rwlock_tryrdlock` instead if it doesn't want to block in case the lock isn't acquired.

Comment: Re, "...I hope yes." Most developers would hope "no" because an application that benefits from reader/writer locks could have so many readers that, for long intervals, there is never a moment when no readers want the lock. If it worked the way you hoped, then that would mean long intervals during which writers get no chance to write. That's the _[starvation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science))_ that @ChristianGibbons mentioned. Most practical reader/writer lock implementations try to balance the needs of the many readers with the needs of the occasional writer.

Answer (score 4):

If Thread Execution Scheduling is supported, you should be able to choose how this works.  From the man page on `pthread_rwlock_rdlock`:

> If  the Thread Execution Scheduling option is supported, and the threads involved in the lock are executing with the scheduling
>   policies SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR, the calling thread shall not acquire
>   the lock if a writer holds
>          the lock or if writers of higher or equal priority are blocked on the lock; otherwise, the calling thread shall acquire the lock.
>
> If the Threads Execution Scheduling option is supported, and the threads involved in the lock are executing with the SCHED_SPORADIC
>   scheduling policy, the calling thread shall not acquire the lock if a
>   writer holds the  lock
>          or if writers of higher or equal priority are blocked on the lock; otherwise, the calling thread shall acquire the lock.

Otherwise it is implementation defined:

> If  the  Thread  Execution  Scheduling  option  is not supported, **it is implementation-defined whether the calling thread
>   acquires the lock when a writer does not hold the lock and there are
>   writers blocked on the lock.** If a
>          writer holds the lock, the calling thread shall not acquire the read lock. If the read lock is not acquired, the calling thread shall
>   block until it can acquire the lock.  The calling thread may deadlock
>   if at the  time  the
>          call is made it holds a write lock.